# Is the word "will" some conjugation of the verb "to be"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, conjugation

I have the impression that the phrase "will be" is using the verb "to be" twice. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. *Will* is a modal verb expressing, among other things, future tense, intention, request, habitual behavior, or probability.

Comment: ...and there is no etymological connection between [will](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=will) and [be](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be) or any other 'be' related form (am, are, is, etc).

Comment: @Mitch: ORIGIN Old English willa (noun), willian (verb), of Germanic origin; related to Dutch wil, German Wille (nouns), also to will and the adverb well .

Comment: @Mitch: there is no etymological connection between *go* and *went*, either. This is called [suppletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion).

Comment: I thought they were related because of other conjugations such as "was" and "were"

Comment: @Jader: Do you mean that 'will' and 'were' are phonetically similar and so might be cognate? if you follow the etymology links and also look at the full set of conjugations of 'to be' in English (and Germanic, and IE), you'll see that 'to be' has several distinct non-cognate forms. And the modal 'will' (and the other English modals) is not cognate with any of the 'to be' forms.

Comment: @Jader: you are right that "was/were" are treated as part of "be", and that they are suppletive. But despite the initial letter, "will" and "was" are not connected.

Comment: @Mitch @Colin I think what got me confused was mainly the fact that my native language doesn't have modal verbs. And also the fact that some questions can be answered with both "I was" and "I will [be]" where the [be] is omitted.